# Execute Cucumber step before/after a specific feature

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I want to specify certain setup and tear down steps for each specific feature file. I've seen hooks that allows code to execute before every scenario, and hooks to execute code before each feature, but I want to specify code to run once before and after all scenarios run for one specific feature.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find a better solution for this?
i am facing same issue.
When i run TestRunner

 my feature file first scenario start with "@before" hook method with tag "@Start"and it start browser 
and last scenario in feature file with "@teardown" tag closes it with "@after" hook method 
Note; To make it work i had to use 
Static Webdriver driver;

The problem is , It restrict me to run multiple feature file execution using same Test Runner.
While Using testrunner for 2 featurefile.
Static Webdriver does not open browser session for 2nd feature file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do you use cucumber-jvm? I found an article that fits your requirement.

http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/

Basically, do not use JUnit @BeforeClass and @AfterClass for this, as they are unaware of Cucumber Hook Tags. You would want Init and Teardown methods to run for certain scenarios only right?

Comment: [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/515) explains it better than the above article.

Comment: Although if you have multiple feature file then Global Hook might be problematic

Comment: Note that the imports in that link are out-of-date. Instead of 'cucumber.annotation.{Before/After}' you should import 'cucumber.api.java.{Before/After}'

Answer (score 21):

It is if you are using junit to run your tests. We use the annotations to create a unit test class and a separate steps class. The standard @Before stuff goes in the steps class, but the @BeforeClass annotation can be used in the main unit test class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"json", "<the report file"},
    features = {"<the feature file>"},
    strict = false,
    glue = {"<package with steps classes"})
public class SomeTestIT {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp(){
       ...
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown(){
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, in order to provide a specific setUp and tearDown for each feature, each feature would need it's own unit test class? It's not ideal, but a it's a reasonable solution.

Comment: There is an alternative you might try, which I have never used, so don't know it works: Add tags to your feature definition and then use the cucumber before annotation like so @Before("tagname"). This needs a bit of extra housekeeping, but then you don't need a testclass per feature so it seems.

Comment: Another approach dawned on me that's even simpler. Just create scenarios for the setup and teardown. It may violate the intention of cucumber, but it's very straightforward and doesn't require any additional modifications

Comment: It's a nice quick'ndirty solution :) Officially however the order of scenario's isn't guaranteed I think and I believe that you can even have the scenario's run in parallel, so you can't do that. Just something to keep in mind..

Comment: I'm unable to run any methods in that class.

Answer (score 6):

**Try this :**

**In feature file :**

```
@tagToIdentifyThatBeginAfterShouldRunForThisFeatureOnly
Feature : My new feature ....
```

**In Stepdefinitions.java** :

```
@Before("@tagToIdentifyThatBeginAfterShouldRunForThisFeatureOnly")
public void testStart() throws Throwable {
}

@After("@tagToIdentifyThatBeginAfterShouldRunForThisFeatureOnly")
public void testStart() throws Throwable {
}
```

Comment: there are no @Begin annotation in Cucumber

Comment: It will run for every scenario in that feature file.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same requirement as yours. As per cucumber-jvm documentantion -
[Cucumber-JVM does not support running a hook only once.](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks)

So I followed null-check approach for a specific variable which is outcome of @Before in cucumber step hook. Something like below.

```
private String token;
public String getToken(){
     if (token == null) {
        token = CucumberClass.executeMethod();
      }
return token;
}
```

In above example let's suppose getToken() method gives you some token required before any scenario could run and you want token only once. This approach will execute your method only the first time i.e when it is null before any scenario starts executing. It significantly reduces the execution time also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is little programming hack.
refer following code

```
public class DemoSteps {

static boolean runOnlyOnce = true;

@Before("@home")
public static void setRunOnlyOnce() {
    if (runOnlyOnce) {
        System.out.println("Execute here");
    }
    runOnlyOnce = false;
}
```

}

```
@home
Business Need: home page

Scenario: test 1
 Given test 1

Scenario: test 2
 Given test 2
```

In above example, if condition in setRunOnlyOnce() method will run only once