# Generate report dynamically after each step execution in cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber, testng

I am trying to get the test report generated dynamically after each step execution in cucumber feature file.Currently we are generating reports in @AfterClass testng annotation .The test reports will be generated only after complete execution.Is there any way to generate report dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

AfterStep seems not to be available in Cucumber-JVM (assuming JVM, based on the syntax you used), for the reasons outlined in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/hpYTCKkQhqw).

If you are able to suffice with AfterScenario hooks instead, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856458/execute-cucumber-step-before-after-a-specific-feature) covers it and an example of what it may look like is below:

```
import cucumber.annotation.After;

@After
public void afterScenario() {
  generateMyDocumentation();
}
```