# Do we have any annotation in cucumber where it will run before any of the tests in the feature file?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, qaf

@Before method will run before every scenario. Do we have an annotation where it run before any of the scenarion and an annotation after all the scenarios have been executed ?

Comment: Afaik, we do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gerkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where you can use different TestNG listeners and annotations. In addition to that if you are using webdriver you can get additional [driver and element listeners](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html) support. For example

```
package my.test.pkg
public class MyClass{
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
       //get executed before suite
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
       //get executed before each xml test

    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
       //get executed before each test case/scenario

    }
    @BeforeGroups(["p1","p2"])
    public void beforeMethod() {
       //get executed before group

    }
    //same for after methods @afterXXXXX

 }
```

You need to add class in config file:

```
<test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test">
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
      <class name="my.test.pkg.Myclass" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

This example is not using listeners. You also can use different listeners.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in comments cucumber does not have an out-of-box solution for this.

But you can create a before hook to run once only using a static flag.

```
private static boolean skipFlag = false;

@Before
public void beforeHook() {

    if(!skipFlag) {
        do stuff
        skipFlag=true;
    }
}
```

Modify the `Before` hook to run for certain tags etc..

The after hook to run at the end is difficult. Either specifically create a scenario or a final step at the end in which does all the after hook stuff. Or you can write the code in a [JVM shutdown hook](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-shutdown-hook-java/), though it will run after all feature files are run.